# Reading XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Hi  I am looking for LINQ query to extract

Level1 Type, subtype

Level4 Path

from the xml sample below.  I am really looking for a single LINQ query so I can step through the resultant data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Toplevels>
  <TopLevel>
    <Level1>
      <Type>Read this</Type>
      <Subtype>Read this</Subtype>
    </Level1>
    <Level2>
      <Level3>
        <Level4>
          <L4Node path="read this" />
        </Level4>

      </Level3>
    </Level2>
  </TopLevel>
  <TopLevel>
    <Level1>
      <Type>Read this</Type>
      <Subtype>Read this</Subtype>
    </Level1>
    <Level2>
      <Level3>
        <Level4>
          <L4Node path="read this" />
        </Level4>

      </Level3>
    </Level2>
  </TopLevel>
  <TopLevel>
    <Level1>
      <Type>Read this</Type>
      <Subtype>Read this</Subtype>
    </Level1>
    <Level2>
      <Level3>
        <Level4>
          <L4Node path="read this" />
        </Level4>

      </Level3>
    </Level2>
  </TopLevel>

</Toplevels>
```

can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i didnt understand what are you trying to do... but ill try to help as i think i understand
try this : 
         var arrayOfNodes = from node in doc.Descendants("Level1")
                      select node.Descendants("otherLevels");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code to get `type` and try to work on your programming skill while trying to do the others

```
     XDocument doc =XDocument.Load("D:\\tmp.xml");

     foreach (XElement element in doc.Element("Toplevels").Elements("TopLevel"))
     {
        string str = element.Element("Level1").Element("type").Value;

        string lvl4 = element.Element("Level1").Element("Level2").Element("Level3").Element("Level4").Element("L4Node").Attribute("path").Value;
     }
```

Comment: How do I also access the level 4 within this same foreach loop?

Comment: @user2744609 it's really not my place to write your code, but i'll do it for this time. please next time try on your own. i'll help you fix if you have bugs but you'll never get the hang of it until you'll have some hands on experience...5 min.

Comment: @user2744609 any time

Comment: Slight change: foreach (XElement element in doc.Element("Toplevels").Elements("TopLevel"))  changed to foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("Toplevels").Elements("TopLevel"))... Thanks for the steer though - really helpful. I had been trying something completely different

Comment: @user2744609 we programs usually do get stuck with certain thinking until someone shake us. welcome to the club

Answer (score 0):

You can search for descendant nodes with `Descendants`.

```
        // using LINQ

        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(XML);


        var subtypes = xdoc.Descendants("Level1").Descendants("Subtype");
        Console.WriteLine("LINQ Level1 Subtype");
        foreach (var el in subtypes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(el.Value);
        }

        var paths = xdoc.Descendants("Level4").Descendants("L4Node").Attributes("path");
        Console.WriteLine("LINQ Level4 Path");
        foreach (var el in paths)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(el.Value);
        }
```

An alternative to LINQ is to use XPath

```
        // using XPath

        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(XML);

        var subtype2 = doc.SelectNodes("/Toplevels/TopLevel/Level1/Subtype");
        Console.WriteLine("XPath Level1 Subtype");
        foreach (XmlNode el in subtype2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(el.InnerText);    
        }

        // using XPath shorter, less efficient
        var subtype3 = doc.SelectNodes("//Level1/Subtype");
        Console.WriteLine("XPath Level1 Subtype");
        foreach (XmlNode el in subtype3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(el.InnerText);
        }
```

Comment: *`Descendants`, `Descendants` everywhere...*

Comment: HI Thanks for your response... I am looking to have Type, Sub Type and Level4 Path as one record per each TopLevel. Does that make more sense?